# android layout animation bottom to top

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-animation

I have created a layout in Android . how to give animation from bottom to top and top to bottom when i pressed  button?

Please find my code below.
**Main Activity**

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(
                MainActivity.this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat);
        View bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet,
                        (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetContainer));
        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);
        overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
        bottomSheetDialog.show();
       

        }
  });
}
```

**Bottom Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
android:background="@color/white">
```

Comment: You mean you want to animate the bottom sheet dialog?

Comment: yes bottom sheet dialog